# Handling application events

Tags: java, android-event, j2objc

I am building a cross-platform app for Android and iOS. So far it's mostly Android and I am learning how to use `j2objc` to translate the code that will later be used by iOS.

On the question of architecture the app - how does one go around passing events in the code that is platform-agnostic. For example, I have a class that downloads a group of files and broadcasts a message using Android broadcast mechanism when each file is downloaded - is there a way to implement this notification exchange in pure Java? Are there any tutorials available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Guava has an eventbus package](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained), which may meet your needs and is included in the j2objc distribution. To use it, include dist/lib/guava-14.0.1.jar (where "dist" is the path to [a recent J2ObjC release](https://github.com/google/j2objc/releases)) in the j2objc command's -classpath, and link with the -lguava flag.

Comment: Thank you, this looks very promising.